# Reduce array over ranges

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array of numbers

```
np.array(([1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5]))
```

And I want to compute the sum over a list of slices

```
((0, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6))
```

Giving

```
[(1 + 4 + 2), (2 + 1), (2 + 1 + 2 + 5)]
```

Is there a nice way to do this in numpy?

Looking for something equivalent to

```
def reduce(a, ranges):
  np.array(list(np.sum(a[low:high]) for (low, high) in ranges))
```

Seems like there is probably some fancy numpy way to do this though. Anyone know?

Comment: you are already using numpy. What do you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). If `a` is the array of values `[1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5]`:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(a, [0,3, 2,4, 2])[::2]
array([ 7,  3, 10], dtype=int32)
```

Here the slice indexes are passed in a list and are summed to return `[ 7,  1,  3,  2, 10]` (i.e. the sums of `a[0:3]`, `a[3:]`, `a[2:4]`, `a[4:]`, `a[2:]`). We only want every other element from this array.

---

Longer alternative approach...

The fact that the slices are of different lengths makes this slightly trickier to vectorise in NumPy, but here is one way you approach the problem.

Given an array of values and an array of slices to make...

```
a = np.array(([1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5]))
slices = np.array([(0, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6)])
```

...create a mask-like array `z` that, for each slice, will be used to "zero-out" the values from `a` we don't want to sum:

```
z = np.zeros((3, 6))
s1 = np.arange(6) >= s[:, 0][:,None]
s2 = np.arange(6) < s[:, 1][:,None]
z[s1 & s2] = 1
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> (z * a).sum(axis=1)
array([  7.,   3.,  10.])
```

A quick `%timeit` shows this is slightly faster than the list comprehension, even though we had to construct `z` and `z * a`. If `slices` is made to be of length 3000, this method is around 40 times quicker.

However note that the array `z` will be of shape `(len(slices), len(a))` which may not be as practical if `a` or `slices` are both very long - an iterative approach might be preferred to avoid large temporary arrays in memory.